# Xcode 11 simulators thrown a warning message each time a test is run

Tags: ios, xctest, xcuitest

Running any XCTest with Xcode 11 and iOS 13/12 simulators throws the below warning message:

> xcodebuild[95489:2342933] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-14802/IDEiOSSupportCore/DVTiPhoneSimulator.m:1890
>
> Details: [DVTiPhoneSimulator -primaryInstrumentsServer was called from
>   the main thread
>
> Object:
>
> Method: -primaryInstrumentsServerWithError:
>
> Thread: {number = 1, name = main}
>
> Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this
>   warning message and any useful information you can provide.

This issue happens a lot when running tests in parallel (or a single test) using xcodebuild build-for-testing & xcodebuild test-without-building. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a fix for it?

Comment: Looks like bug in the iOS support code for iPhone Simulator, specifically actions are not happening on the correct thread (probably should be called as a background task.) I would file a radar.. Does unchecking the run tests in parallel option make the problem go away?

Comment: I am not running the tests in parallel via XCode, instead running them via xcodebuild from the terminal

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in my own tests, pretty clearly appears to be an Apple issue.

Comment: Same here, the only tests which succeed are the ones on the "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)" simulator..no idea why

Comment: @markw. Facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: nothing yet. I even logged an issue with Apple - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123020. Please feel free to raise your concerns there as well so that Apple knows it's affecting everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Link to source for answer https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123020#392637 it seems it would be solved on iOS 13.2

Comment: I am on 14.4 this issue still exists!

Answer (score 1):

Apple finally fixed this on iOS 13.2, so sharpen your downloading knives :)

Comment: I am on 14.4 this issue still exists!

Comment: lol, I have the same issue on 14.4, hope an answer can be found that doesn't include downloading updates.